# Spring boot Turbine.stream with ssl Not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, turbine

We are trying to enable https in turbine stream. And we are facing below problem:

```
ERROR 10644 --- [o-eventloop-3-1] r.n.p.h.s.ServerRequestResponseConverter : Invalid HTTP request recieved. Decoder error.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: ￭\ￇ:4'|"￀+￀/￀,￀0ￌﾩￌﾨￌￌ￀     ￀￀
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:130) ~[netty-codec-http-4.0.27.Final.jar!/:4.0.27.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:84) ~[netty-codec-http-4.0.27.Final.jar!/:4.0.27.Final]
```

Please provide any suggestion
Thank you.

**UPDATE**
Do we need to enable ssl to message broker which is handling the stream

**Code**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableTurbineStream
public class DemoHystrixApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoHystrixApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value ="/test")
    public String helloHystrix() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String output = null;
        try {
            output = mapper.writeValueAsString("{ \"message\" : \"test : Welcome to test Notification Detail Page.\"}");
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return output;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value ="/test2")
    public String testhello() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String output = null;
        try {
            output = mapper.writeValueAsString("{ \"message\" : \"test : Welcome to test1 Page.\"}");
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

**POM Dependency**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-turbine-stream</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8083
spring.cloud.consul.host=localhost
spring.cloud.consul.port=8500
spring.application.name=testApp
security.basic.enabled=false
eureka.client.enabled=false
server.ssl.key-store=consul.pfx
server.ssl.key-password=changeit
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.trust-store=root.pfx
server.ssl.trust-store-password=changeit
server.ssl.trust-store-type=PKCS12
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.scheme=https
```

Comment: Please provide any update. It is working fine on http but not on https.